# upgrading iphone 4 to iOS 5

Tags: ios, iphone, upgrade

I updated my iPhone 4 from iOS 4 to iOS 5 a while back. Now I am trying to update my wife's iPhone 4 without jumping all the way to iOS 6, so how do I determine what model I need?

```
5.0.1 (3GS): iPhone2,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw
5.0.1 (4 GSM): iPhone3,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw
5.0.1 (4 CDMA): iPhone3,3_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw
5.0.1 (4S): iPhone4,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw
```

My phone version is listed as 5.0.1 (9A405). Can you help me understand which restore file is the right one? And will these files restore my phone or simply upgrade to the next OS?

Answer (score 3):

The kind folks behind http://iossupportmatrix.com have done the work to catalog all model identifiers (and also list the minimum and maximum versions of iOS for each model).

In your case, the iPhone 4 needs iPhone3,1_xxxx.ipsw

[image]

If you use a restore image, it wipes the device and loads that version of iOS. At that point, you could restore from an older or equivalent level OS backup or set things up newly by syncing content.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was greatly helpful. Are there upgrade files that don't restore but just upgrade?

Comment: Apple provides delta upgrade packages for OTA updates, but I've never heard of anyone capturing those let alone setting up the infrastructure to deliver them properly to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade to a version other than the latest unless your shsh blobs are saved or you use TinyUmbrella to patch your hosts file.